# Trying to compile a x86 C program on a x64 RedHat environment [Part 2]

Tags: c

Still following the saga of a Cobol developer handling C programs on a environment migration.

I think we could manage 90% of the problems so far and most of our C programs are now compiling fine on the RHEL 64 bits.

Friday we found another module that is not compiling and I hope to be the last one.

I am receiving two warnings, but I have no idea about it and our make does not allow us to compile it properly.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include </public/prod/src/mfqinc.h>

static FILE *infile = NULL;
static FILE *outfile = NULL;
char inbuf[1024], blockrec[10240];
static char workstring[1024];
static char workstring0[1024];
static char gra2533h [8];
static char gra2401h [8] ;
static char gra2501h [8] ;
static char gra2506h [8] ;
static char  crtn[1]  ; /* {"0x0A"};*/

int i;
int z;
int f;
int resulisn;
int j;
int d;
int ctrrec;
int nb_ecrit;
static int longueur;

void initworkstring()
{
    extern char workstring [1024];
    int ik;
    for (ik=0; ik < 1024 ;ik++)
    {
        workstring [ik]  = NULL;
    }
}

void ecriture()
{
    extern char workstring [1024];
    extern int longueur;
    extern int ctrrec;
    nb_ecrit =  fwrite(workstring,sizeof(char),longueur,outfile);
    ctrrec++;

    if ( nb_ecrit != longueur )
    {
        printf("andlog:erreur d ecriture ");
        printf("Ecrit: %i",nb_ecrit);
        printf("Erreur no: %i",errno);
        exit(60);
    }
}

static void errarg(char *errmsg)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR - %s\nCommand format :\n\t",errmsg);
    fprintf(stderr,"         :                  \n");
    /*    exit(1); */
}
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( argc < 3 )
    {
        printf("<<<  Programme : and015                  >>>\n");
        printf("<<<  Nombre de parametres incorrect      >>>\n");
        printf("<<<  Remove catacteres speciaux          >>>\n");
        printf("<<<  Param # 1 = nom du fichier d'input  >>>\n");
        printf("<<<  Param # 2 = nom du fichier d'output >>>\n");
        printf("\n");
        exit(10);
    }
    if ((infile = fopen(argv[1],"rb")) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Erreur sur fichier input \n");
        exit(20);
    }

    if ((outfile = fopen(argv[2],"wb")) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Erreur sur fichier output \n");
        exit(30);
    }

    initworkstring();
    /* remplir les table de catacteres */
    crtn[0]=0x0a;

    gra2533h[0]=0x1b;
    gra2533h[1]=0x5b;
    gra2533h[2]=0x32;
    gra2533h[3]=0x35;
    gra2533h[4]=0x3b;
    gra2533h[5]=0x33;
    gra2533h[6]=0x33;
    gra2533h[7]=0x48;

    gra2401h[0]=0x1b;
    gra2401h[1]=0x5b;
    gra2401h[2]=0x32;
    gra2401h[3]=0x34;
    gra2401h[4]=0x3b;
    gra2401h[5]=0x30;
    gra2401h[6]=0x31;
    gra2401h[7]=0x48;

    gra2501h[0]=0x1b;
    gra2501h[1]=0x5b;
    gra2501h[2]=0x32;
    gra2501h[3]=0x35;
    gra2501h[4]=0x3b;
    gra2501h[5]=0x30;
    gra2501h[6]=0x31;
    gra2501h[7]=0x48;

    gra2506h[0]=0x1b;
    gra2506h[1]=0x5b;
    gra2506h[2]=0x32;
    gra2506h[3]=0x35;
    gra2506h[4]=0x3b;
    gra2506h[5]=0x30;
    gra2506h[6]=0x36;
    gra2506h[7]=0x48;

while (fgets(inbuf,1024,infile) != NULL )
{
    i=0;
    j=0;
    d=0;
    for (i=0; i < 1024 ; i++)
    {
        if ( inbuf [i] == NULL )
        {
            i = 9999;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( inbuf[i] == 0x1b )
            {
                i++;
                           d=0;
                for (d=0  ;d < 8; d++)
                {
                    if ( inbuf[i] == 0x48 )
                    {
                                         j= j-d;
                                         workstring[j]=0x0a;
                        d=99;
                     }
                    else

                    {
                                    if (inbuf[i] == 0x6d)
                                     {
                                         j= j-d;
                                         workstring[j]=0x0a;
                        d=99;

                                     }

                                    else
                                    {

                                      if (inbuf[i] == 0x53)
                                        {
                                         j=j-d; 
                                         workstring[j]=0x0a; 
                                         d=99;
                                        }
                                      else

                                       {
                        workstring[j] = inbuf[i];
                        j++;
                        i++;
                                       }
                                    }
                    }

                }  /* end du for*/

            }/*fin du if 01b*/

            else
            {
                workstring[j] = inbuf[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        /*   mettre dans workstring */
        workstring [j] = inbuf [i];
    }
    strcat(workstring,crtn);
    longueur = j ;
    ecriture ();
    initworkstring();

}  /* fin du while */

fclose(infile);
fclose(outfile);
exit(0);
}
```

Those are the warnings I am having.

```
/exp/prod/src>gcc -m64 mfqlog.c -o mfqlog
mfqlog.c: In function 'initworkstring':
mfqlog.c:48:20: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   workstring [ik]  = NULL;
                    ^
mfqlog.c: In function 'main':
mfqlog.c:146:18: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
   if ( inbuf [i] == NULL )
```

Really sorry to bother with this question. But I really need to compile this code.

The funny fact is that the program is working (probably, for some unknown reason to me, the program was compiling before and it is not anymore due to changes on the compiler maybe?!?) on our actual environment, but if we try to compile it will fail and the only way to make it working is restoring the executable backup.

As we are moving to a new 64 bits environment, it has to be recompiled.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. The message clearly states the issue: you're comparing an integer type (namely `char`, it looks like), to a pointer-typed constant, and you are better equipped to know the intent of this code than we are. If you want to suppress these warnings, use `0` instead of `NULL` in these contexts. Will it work? I don't know, since I am not the author of this program nor do I have insight into his or her decisions.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov They indicate constraint violations, i.e. the program is erroneous according to the C Standard and no behaviour is defined for any executable as a result.   So it would be wise to treat them as errors regardless of the wording that the compiler used in reporting them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL is defined as (void*)0. Replace NULL with '\0' or 0.

```
workstring [ik]  = '\0';

if ( inbuf [i] == '\0' )
```

Comment: `NULL` is also allowed to be defined as `0`, which was probably the case on the system where the code previously worked.